# How to Create a Link to a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, popup

Here is what im working on... A maximizable and minimizable pop-up that is called by an hyperlink.

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  .pop_out {
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  }
  .minimized {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .maximized {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    /* Whatever styling you want when maximized, as long as you add the same styling to minimized class to change it back */
  }
  .close_pop {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .close_pop:hover {
    color: red;
  }
  .expand_collapse {
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    height: 3px;
  }
  .expand_collapse:hover {
    color: #ccc;
  }
  a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var max = true;

  function expand_collapse(elem) {
    var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (max === false) {
      elem.innerHTML = "&#9660;";
      top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", false);
      top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", true);
      max = true;
    } else if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
      elem.innerHTML = "&#9650;";
      top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", true);
      top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", false);
      max = false
    }
  }

  function close_pop(elem) {
    var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    top_div.style.display = 'none';
    if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
      max = false;
    }
  }
</script>
<a href="#">CLICK HERE</a><!--Right Here -->
<div style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
  <div class="pop_out maximized">
    <div style="padding:2px;position:relative;"> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Tab 1</span>
      <span style="position:absolute;right:15px;">
     <span class="expand_collapse" onclick="expand_collapse(this);">&#9660;</span>
      <span class="close_pop" onclick="close_pop(this);">&times</span></span>
    </div>
    <div style="background:white;font-size:15px;padding:2px;">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
      laborum.</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

But the pop up opens with the page and i want the pop up to only be opened when the hyperlink commented is clicked and not when the page is loaded. Any help will be much appreciated. I have tried different methods on the hyperlink but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up element isn't being hidden on initial page load.

Add style to the pop-up element in CSS.

```
display:none
```

Give the pop-up element an ID attribute for easier Javascript targeting
`id="pop1"`

Add attribute to the hyperlink

```
onclick="open_pop('#pop1')"
```

Add javascript function

```
function open_pop(elem)
{
   elem.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Or to synchronise more effectively with your code, give the pop-up one of your custom classes to modify the display style.

I would also consider using ID's for Javascript selection as opposed to crawling through parents which could break the code if children elements or added or removed from the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-popup').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.close_pop').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
.pop_out {
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
.minimized {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.maximized {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  /* Whatever styling you want when maximized, as long as you add the same styling to minimized class to change it back */
}
.close_pop {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
.close_pop:hover {
  color: red;
}
.expand_collapse {
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  height: 3px;
}
.expand_collapse:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show-popup" href="#">CLICK HERE</a>
<!--Right Here -->
<div class="popup" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
  <div class="pop_out maximized">
    <div style="padding:2px;position:relative;"> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Tab 1</span>
      <span style="position:absolute;right:15px;">
     <span class="expand_collapse" onclick="expand_collapse(this);">&#9660;</span>
      <span class="close_pop">&times</span></span>
    </div>
    <div style="background:white;font-size:15px;padding:2px;">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
      laborum.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

in simple code,

html

```
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

javascript

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

I could not share my jsfiddle link. so this helps you i guess.

---

### OR

Just make the div `style = "display:none"` on mouse click toggle the display.